How to track if Angular patchValue is already finished?
At the beginning of the application, i get server data and patch it to my form. Afterwards i would like to mark my form as pristine, so i can disable the submit button until user changes something. The problem is that patching takes so much time that i cant set my form as pristine. Only with setTimeout i can accomplish that which is a terrible solution. Any ideas how could i track if the patching is over or any alternative solution ?
Thanks !
here i m trying to patch and than mark as pristine :
private _loadFormData() {
    if (this.detail) {
      this.caseOverviewForm?.patchValue(this.detail);
      this._loadDynamicFormOptions();
      setTimeout(() => this.caseOverviewForm.markAsPristine(),3000)
    }
  }

UPDATE : carried the setTimeout here, works a bit faster
 private _loadDynamicFormOptions(): void {
        this.categoryList$ = this.service
          .getCategoryList(this._optionPayload())
          .pipe(mapAndPatch(this.caseOverviewForm, FormFields.category, this.detail.id!));
    
        this.subCategoryList$ =
          this._updateSubDropDownList(FormFields.category, FormFields.subCategory, OptionsType.caseCategory)?.pipe(
            mapAndPatch(this.caseOverviewForm, FormFields.subCategory, this.detail.id!),
          ) ?? of([]);
        setTimeout(() => this.caseOverviewForm.markAsPristine())
      }

Here trying to disable submit button
<t-button
      [tooltipConfig]="tooltipConfig"
      [disabled]="caseOverviewForm.invalid || caseOverviewForm.pristine"
      [type]="buttonTypes.POSITIVE"
      [size]="buttonSizes.LARGE"
      (click)="submitChanges()"
    ></t-button>


Patching a value to the form should be synchronous. Maybe in the this._loadDynamicFormOptions() function there is some asynchronous action which marks the form as dirty?

@JSONDerulo yes i guess thats the problem. i m updating my code now. Any suggestions ?

mapAndPatch is this a custom RxJS operator? Any chance you can mark the form as pristine inside the operator?

unfortunately no, self written method in an other class which is used in many forms

You have some other asynchronous actions which mark the form as dirty again. To get the right timing, you can use combineLatest:
private _loadDynamicFormOptions(): void {
  this.categoryList$ = this.service
    .getCategoryList(this._optionPayload())
    .pipe(mapAndPatch(this.caseOverviewForm, FormFields.category, this.detail.id!));
    
  this.subCategoryList$ =
    this._updateSubDropDownList(FormFields.category, FormFields.subCategory, OptionsType.caseCategory)?.pipe(
      mapAndPatch(this.caseOverviewForm, FormFields.subCategory, this.detail.id!),
    ) ?? of([]);
  
  combineLatest(this.categoryList$, this.subCategoryList$)
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(() => this.caseOverviewForm.markAsPristine());
}


unfortunately didnt work out

You have the wrong impression, patchValue does not change the pristine property. Whatever is doing it, is not in the code you shared.
Stackblitz Demo

If you want to validate once the user touched the form, try changing the button validation to.
<t-button
  [tooltipConfig]="tooltipConfig"
  [disabled]="caseOverviewForm.touched && caseOverviewForm.invalid"
  [type]="buttonTypes.POSITIVE"
  [size]="buttonSizes.LARGE"
  (click)="submitChanges()"
></t-button>

You could also try the variant.
  [disabled]="caseOverviewForm.touched"

